# Folder Locker in c#

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5, windows-xp

Please help to decipher on how the folder locker works?
I would like to create a folder hide/lock functionality using c#?

any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Just to clarify - what do you mean by "folder locker"? Is your question about security and locking users out from accessing certain folders?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by locking a folder?

Answer (score 2):

You could refer this [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/Unique_Folder_Protection.aspx) article on how to protect\lock folder.